# WindowsPhone Cordova 5 PushPlugin no registration

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, push

I'm having trouble with Cordova using the `PushPlugin` at

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

I added it to my WP8 App and everything seems to work, but the registration is not successful.
Before I used the old version of the `PushPlugin` at `github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin` and this works perfectly. but not the new one.

Is there a full working example to this? Google didn't help..

Besides the given code on github:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "12345679"},
     "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );
```

Maybe there's something missing? I'm using the same code as given in the example..

And it is possible to send additional data through the Microsoft cloud service to the device? Like it is possible on android?